# Returning the compared input as-is if the IF function is true or false

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a pre-built-in function to run a check on a function and change or just reuse that input depending on if it's true or false?  So for example currently to do what I want to do, I have #long_formula, and I want to suppress that output if it's negative.  My if statement would look like IF(#long_Formula>=0,#long_formula,"").  Is there a more compact and cleaner way to perform this comparison?  I'm trying to avoid spreading the calculation over multiple cells, and I don't always want to return an empty cell as the false condition.  I can make my own function, but it always seems to not play nice with arrays when I do so (because my VBA knowledge is very limited).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Excel 365 you can use the [`LET()` function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999):

```
=LET(f,long_formula,IF(f>=0,f,""))
```